# MS SQL use trigger to update field

Tags: sql-server, ms-sql

I have a table with fields for length, width, and area. I want to use a trigger to calculate the area when a new record is inserted or an existing record is updated. How do I do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Use computed column. `fieldname datatype AS (field expression)`

Comment: Too broad, you need to do some research and tell us what you are having trouble with. Then you may get other and maybe even better solutions in a simpler way. Give it a shot, [edit], and let everyone know what's up afterwards!!!